# ATTrackingManager stopped working in iOS 15

Tags: swift, ios15

ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization stopped working on ios 15. Application rejected from Apple.

Comment: Yes, This Problem has been solved. Please follow below two links.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690607
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690762

Answer (score 29):

According to the discussion in Apple Developer Forum, you need to add delay for about one second when calling requestTrackingAuthorization.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690607

Example:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
          ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
        // Tracking authorization completed. Start loading ads here.
        // loadAd()
      })
})
```

P.S.
Also if you have requesting push notification permission, firstly you need request push notification then request tracking authorization with a delay =>

```
    private func requestPushNotificationPermission() {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
                ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
                    // Tracking authorization completed. Start loading ads here.
                    // loadAd()
                })
            })
        }})
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem has been solved, just call it in `applicationDidBecomeActive`:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690762

Comment: Yes, Solved.
Thanks for update. It can solve by this solution as well
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690607

Answer (score 10):

Make sure your iPhone's Settings -> Privacy -> Tracking is enabled. Otherwise, it won't prompt for request Aurthorization.

Comment: OMG! Dude, u saved me!

Answer (score 10):

Follow by apple doc:

> Calls to the API only prompt when the application state is `UIApplicationStateActive`.

So, we need to call `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization` on
`applicationDidBecomeActive` of `AppDelegate`.

> But If you're using scenes (see Scenes), UIKit will not call this method. Use `sceneDidBecomeActive(_:)` instead to restart any tasks or refresh your app’s user interface. UIKit posts a `didBecomeActiveNotification` regardless of whether your app uses scenes.

So, my approach is to register on `addObserver` on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` such as:

`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleRequestEvent), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)`

on `handleRequestEvent`:

`requestPermission() // func call ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)`

Hope this helps. It's work for me.

Comment: calling the tracking in sceneDidBecomeActive worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Calling it on sceneDidBecomeActive didn't work for me on iOS 16.1 simulator nor device, but registering for UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification did!

Answer (score 0):

To take a closer look at this issue: the `+[ATTrackingManager requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler:]` method internally checks `-[UIApplication applicationState]` to determine if the state is `UIApplicationStateActive`.

```
AppTrackingTransparency`+[ATTrackingManager requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler:]:
    0x1c6834ac4 <+300>: bl     0x1c6835ca0               ; objc_msgSend$applicationStateActive
->  0x1c6834ac8 <+304>: mov    x21, x0
    0x1c6834acc <+308>: mov    x0, x20
    0x1c6834ad0 <+312>: bl     0x1c6835de0               ; objc_msgSend$isApplicationExtension
    0x1c6834ad4 <+316>: cbz    w21, 0x1c6834b70          ; <+472>
    0x1c6834ad8 <+320>: tbnz   w0, #0x0, 0x1c6834b70     ; <+472>
    0x1c6834adc <+324>: mov    x0, x20
    0x1c6834ae0 <+328>: bl     0x1c6835bc0               ; objc_msgSend$_performTCCAccessRequest

AppTrackingTransparency`+[ATTrackingManager applicationStateActive]:
# x0 = (id)_TtC7SwiftUIP33_ACC2C5639A7D76F611E170E831FCA49118SwiftUIApplication
# x1 = (SEL)applicationSate
->  0x1c683485c <+44>: bl     0x1c6835ec0               ; objc_msgSend$performSelector:
```

If you want to request Tracking Authorization even when the `applicationState` is not `UIApplicationStateActive`, there's a way to directly call the Private API `+[ATTrackingManager _performTCCAccessRequest]`, but it's not a recommended approach.

```swift
(ATTrackingManager.self).perform(Selector(("_performTCCAccessRequest")))
```

Additionally, calling `+[ATTrackingManager requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler:]` within `-sceneDidBecomeActive:` will not work. This is because, in a Scene-Based App, the `-[UIScene activationState]` of all connected scenes must be updated before the value of `-[UIApplication applicationState]` is updated. Consequently, during `-sceneDidBecomeActive:`, `-[UIApplication applicationState]` might not be `UIApplicationStateActive`.

Furthermore, the `UIApplicationDelegate`'s `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` method is not called in a Scene-Based App. However, the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` is still posted even in a Scene-Based App, thus, using `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` is an appropriate approach.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623003-applicationstate?language=objc

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622956-applicationdidbecomeactive?language=objc

Although [duongvanthai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70404174/17473716) is correct, I'm writing this post for those curious about the principle behind it.