# Xamarin App Tracking Transparency Dialog does not appear since iOS 15

Tags: ios, xamarin, privacy, ios15, apptrackingtransparency

Since I started building my App for iOS 15 in Xamarin the Dialog with the Tracking Usage Description does not disappear anymore and it does not pass Apple's review.

I tried with my iPhone 12 mini and also with various simulators. Simulators for iOS 14.5 did show the dialog, devices running iOS 15 do not

- "Allow Apps to Request to Track" in the settings is activated

Happy for any help.

It was implemented according to the instructions on [this page](https://luismts.com/app-tracking-transparency-permission-xamarin-forms-ios/)

Comment: This is a known issue , could you try to move the call into the `DidBecomeActive` in `SceneDelegate` class ?   Don't use dependency service , just call it directly in DidBecomeActive method .

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT Thank you so much for the hint. We use Xamarin to build the app. I put it in `OnActivated` which seems to be the equivalent for `DidBecomeActive`.
Thank you!

Comment: @Ginbob89 I hope this can solve your problem [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312640/attrackingmanager-stopped-working-in-ios-15/69341221#69341221)

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue On Xamarin.iOS:

Put the "RequestTrackingAuthorization" code
in AppDelegate.cs >> function: OnActivated()
instead of AppDelegate.cs >> function: FinishedLaunching().

The answer provided by "Tran Canh" is correct, where "AppDelegate's applicationDidBecomeActive method" is "AppDelegate.cs >> function: OnActivated()".

Answer (score -1):

I was meet this same issue. I was calling the ATT request from Appdelegate in  **application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method.

I've changed to call the request from the AppDelegate's **applicationDidBecomeActive** method and it worked